# "XML data, foreach element loop, post web service"

Tags: php, xml, api, foreach

I want to post 1 "listing" tag from XML data each time. 
I could not. 
White page turning. 
I will be glad if you help me.

api.xml

```
<listings>
<listing>
<Sku>HBV00000H74DE</Sku>
<MerchantSku>Encok-D02</MerchantSku>
<ProductName>Baseus D02 Kablosuz Bluetooth 5.0 Kulaklık renk beyaz</ProductName>
<Price>294,10</Price>
<AvailableStock>0</AvailableStock>
<DispatchTime>1</DispatchTime>
<MaximumPurchasableQuantity>0</MaximumPurchasableQuantity>
</listing>
<listing>
<Sku>HBV00000H74DD</Sku>
<MerchantSku>Encok-S09</MerchantSku>
<ProductName>Baseus S09 Encok Manyetik Kablosuz Bluetooth Mikrofonlu Kulaklık renk silver</ProductName>
<Price>136,08</Price>
<AvailableStock>1</AvailableStock>
<DispatchTime>1</DispatchTime>
<MaximumPurchasableQuantity>0</MaximumPurchasableQuantity>
</listing>
```

xml goes on like this.

I can send data of 1 product.

---

```html
<?php 
$xmldata = simplexml_load_file('api.xml');

$output = "<listings>";
foreach($xmldata->children() as $listing) { 
        $output .= "<listing>";
        $output .= "<Sku>" . $listing->Sku ."</Sku>";
        $output .= "<MerchantSku>". $listing->MerchantSku ."</MerchantSku>";
        $output .= "<ProductName>". $listing->ProductName ."</ProductName>";
        $output .= "<Price>". $listing->Price ."</Price>";
        $output .= "<AvailableStock>". $listing->AvailableStock ."</AvailableStock>";
        $output .= "<DispatchTime>". $listing->DispatchTime ."</DispatchTime>";
        $output .= "<MaximumPurchasableQuantity>". $listing->MaximumPurchasableQuantity ."</MaximumPurchasableQuantity>";
        $output .= "</listing>";
}
$output = "</listings>";

$service_url = 'https://.../inventory-uploads';
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $output);
$header = array(    
'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode('user:passw'),
'Content-Type: application/xml'
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
$result .=  $curl_response = curl_exec($curl); 
?>
```

I would like to update the product price and inventory with this transaction.

Comment: typo `$output = "</listings>";` should be `.=`

Comment: You might also want to have a look at XSLT processing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT